# Mysql query cache handling on multiple instances of same linux machine

Tags: mysql

I have 4 mysql db instances on a common linux server(port 3306, 3307, 3308, 3309).I am trying to improve the query cache hit rate by tweaking with server variables.

My doubt is , If I login into port 3306 instance and run the commands to show sever and status variables(eg show status like '%Qcache%'),  is the result common of all the instances or is it specific to that instance only.

So, I want to know that will I have set the variables for each instance or setting them for will be applicable to all(in this case the variables are related to query_cache)

Comment: @Samkit Jain , Thanks for the answer, and one more doubt that I have is ,since the RAM of Linux is common to all instances , I guess we have to take care that all the variables values like buffer pool size, log buffer size, query cache size of all 4 instances combined together  do not cross the IN-MEMORY size available ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have four separate MySQL server daemons running each one can have its configuration parameters set separately. It is possible to make them the same on all four instances by using a common base my.cnf between them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 4 mysql process running on the ports `3306, 3307, 3308, 3309` than `show status like '%Qcache%'` will have different value for different process.

Additional info about the variables:

```
Qcache_free_blocks       numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_free_memory       numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_hits              numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_inserts       numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_lowmem_prunes     numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_not_cached        numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_queries_in_cache  numeric    GLOBAL
Qcache_total_blocks      numeric    GLOBAL
```

From the above we can see that this is at **global level not at session level**.

Isn't it that simple?